# Uploadify and HTTP 401 challenges. Why doesn't it work consistently?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, uploadify

Using Uploadify plugin which uses jQuery and SWF.  Some web servers it works, some it does not.  Seems to get a HTTP 401 Not Authorized when attempting to upload.  Might be related to SWF.  In Fiddler, when it does not work, seem to get this Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication, but when it does work, we don't get the Session Based Authentication.  Is this a network routing issue?  Proxy Issue?  Any suggestions on fix

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Mon, 22 Nov 2010 22:20:45 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1697
```

**`Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication`**

Comment: It is seemingly like the best solution is to not use Uploadify, as nice as an interface as it is.  But if no flash, then we lose the ability to upload multiple files at a time.  Any other non-SWF jQuery plugins that anyone can recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To anyone wanting to use the Uploadify plugin with Windows Authentication.  Don't do it.  Not just Uploadify, but any of them that use Flash files.  Try another plug in instead.  We used this one and it worked just great, no issues.  It does not use any Flash.

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Answer (score 3):

Uploadify uses Flash for uploading. I think the problem here is related to a bug in Flash that makes Uploadify use a separate session. Even though the user's session is authorized to upload, that authorization is not extended to the Uploadify session.

One solution to this is issue is to make your own custom authentication for uploading. You could consider issuing a sort of access token to the user that can be passed as a parameter to Uploadify, and passed along when uploading files.

Comment: I agree with paragraph 1, but I strongly disagree with paragraph 2 :) Usually, passing on the right session ID manually in the uploader's options is enough. (Will upvote when I have votes again)

Comment: So as I understand it, the issue is a bug in SWF files that they don't always carry the authentication headers properly, so could you create a aspx page that returns the content type of shockwave flash and do a Response.BinaryWrite to get the file.  Maybe that would get around it. Not sure.

Comment: @Pekka: That sounds like a good solution. My first attempt when I ran into this issue involved passing along the session ID and swapping out the actual Uploadify session before the request was processed. It raised a couple of other issues though, so I ended up saving the user's session ID in the database as a "token" and passing it along with the Uploadify request.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently.

In my case I was using IIS with windows authentication enabled (no anonymous access). This  prevented Flash from uploading files because it ran the upload process as a non-authenticated separate session. To resolve I allowed anonymous access on the handler files only and upload now works great.

Comment: Can you please elaborate and give me the steps? I'm having the same problem.